# Three file not found errors before Grub menu appears - caused by 12.10 upgrade

Tags: 12.10, grub2

After just upgrading to 12.10, I see three Error: File Not Found lines flash up on the screen at the very start of bootup, just before the grub menu appears. The system still works properly after that.

Just wondering why, and how to fix it.

Comment: Getting the same since some years... Never figured how to fix this (but I never tried to reinstall grub).